# Subring of continuous function

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the  set of all function  $f(x)$  such that $ f(q) =0$  for all  $q  \in  \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$  a subring of $C[0,1]?$

My attempt: I think yes, because both  $f- g \in C[0,1]$, and $ fg$ $\in  C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, such set is closed under multiplication and subtraction. However, in order to show that it is a [unit subring](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitRing.html) you should also check that this set  contains the multiplicative identity, i. e. the constant function $1$. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of *ring* in this context. If rings are required to have multiplicative identities, then the answer is *no* since the function $x \mapsto 1$ is not in your set. However, if rings are not required to have multiplicative identities, then your set indeed forms a subring.

For a more concrete answer, note that the set you describe only consists only of the zero function $x \mapsto 0$ because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Thus, I guess the most standard answer is that your set is a ring (with unit), but not a subring (with unit) since the multiplicative unit $x \mapsto 0$ of the subset does not coincide with the multiplicative unit $x \mapsto 1$ of $C[0,1]$.